# How to expand the background color to fit the parent in my case?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a loading element that is on top of my view (it covers from top to bottom)

my html is like

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="loading">
            loading....
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

My css

```
.main{
    height: calc(100vh - 80px - 50px); // I need to have set height for other display reasons
    overflow: auto;
}

.parent {
    height:100%;
}

.loading {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;    
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    opacity: 0.1;    
}
```

my `.main` is a long page that usually has a scrollbar.

Please see my jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/u0em2wdn/

Noticed as soon as I scroll down, I see the white area that is not covered by red.

The problem I have here is my loading div only cover the current. However, as soon as I scroll, the coverage with red is gone. Is there a way I can expand my loading div all the way to the bottom even when scrolling?

PS: I know I can change the .main height to 100% but I would have bigger issue with my page.

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **position:absolute;** to **position: fixed;** for **.loading**

```css
.main{
    height: calc(100vh - 80px - 50px); // I need to have set height for other display reasons
    overflow: auto;
}

.parent {
    height:100%;
}

.loading {
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;    
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    opacity: 0.1; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;   
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="parent">
    <div class="loading">
        loading....
    </div>
<div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
 <div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
    <div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>
<div>
    This is a text
</div>

<div>
    This is a text
</div>

</div>
```

Hope this help